# how to prevent editing of any entered record in django model

Tags: python, django

I have a condition where I wish to prevent editing of any entered record in certain django models in my application. At the same time I wish to allow add permission for the same and also allow permission to view the existing records of the model. I am aware of the readonly_fields option in the ModelAdmin. But I am looking for a generic option, so that it can be inherited for some of the models.

```
class ReadOnlyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = []
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
            return list(self.readonly_fields) + \
                [field.name for field in obj._meta.fields]

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
            return True  #False originally

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

class CompanyAdmin(ReadOnlyAdmin):
     list_display = ('name','website')
```

> The error if return True for has_add_permission:
>
> ```
> AttributeError at /admin/tracker/company/add/
>
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>
> http://myhost:8000/admin/tracker/company/add/ Django Version:
>
> 1.6.5 Exception Type: AttributeError Exception Value:
>
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose overriding the read only method is the obvious route:

```
class ReadOnlyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        # your logic

class YourAdmin(ReadOnlyAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: Have tried this method, but it creates problem while adding a new record. If you know how to allow add permission with this logic, I will be happy to implement it!

Comment: Could you add that error to the original question as it is likely the problem to solve

Comment: Sorry! Had edited your answer.Now I have updated my original post!

Comment: When you add a new entry there's no obj yet, so your snippet will never work. You need an if/else block that checks if there's an instance and return the proper readonly fields accordingly

Comment: I have tried the if obj: else block also, but it throws up the error